# Symmetric positive semidefinite matrix is the square of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I am trying to show that matrix $A$ is symmetric positive semidefinite if and only if there exists a symmetric matrix $B$ such that $B^2 = A$.

Here is my solution, any comments?

I have attempted to solve this with diagonalization of A and using the determinants of A to show there is a matrix $B^2$ that equals $A$.  If there is a matrix $B$ such that $B = P \operatorname{diag}(\lambda^{1/2}...\lambda_n^{1/2})P^{-1}$  Let matrix  $  D = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1^{1/2}...\lambda_n^{1/2})$ if  $ PBP^{-1} = D$ then $\det|D| = \det|P|\det|B|\det|P^{-1}$ where $\det|P| \cdot 1/\det|P| =  1$, therefore there exists a matrix $B^2$ where $\det|A| = \det|B| \cdot \det|B|$ and this matrix $B^2 = A$.

To extrapolate further:  $PAP^{-1} = D^2$

$$ PAP^{-1} = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda^{1/2}...\lambda_n^{1/2}) = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda^{1/2}...\lambda_n^{1/2}) \cdot \operatorname{diag}(\lambda^{1/2}...\lambda_n^{1/2}) = PBP^{-1}  PBP^{-1}$$

$$PB(P^{-1}P)BP^{-1} = PB^2P^{-1} = PAP^{-1}$$  reduce to $B^2 = A$

Comment: "iff" means "if and only if", so there are two statements. Can you prove one of two directions: if such $B$ exists, then $A$ is symmetric  positive definite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have (more or less) correctly shown that if $A$ is positive semidefinite, then there is a $B$ such that $A = B^2$.

Now, suppose that $B$ is symmetric, and $A = B^2$.  We note that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $\lambda = \mu^2$ for some eigenvalue $\mu$ of $B$. The eigenvalues of $B$ are real.  Thus, the eigenvalues of $A$ are non-negative.  Moreover, $A$ is symmetric since $B$ is symmetric.

Since $A$ is symmetric with non-negative eigenvalues, it is positive semidefinite, as desired.